# Incorporate formula using Left and Right function

Tags: excel

I am trying to allocate points for football scores. Problem is that the scores are sent in one cell as eg "3-1" I want to be able to first of all put in another column, that because 3-1 is Home win it shows as Home and if it was "1-3" would show as Away and if it was "1-1" show as draw.
Then in another column compare predicted result with actual result and have formula that calculates points as follows Home or Away win = 2 points Draw= 3 points
If correct goals for home team get 1 extra point and if correct goals for away team get 1 extra point and an extra point if all correct
This means if you have correct score and its either home or away win you get 5 points but if its a draw you get 6 points if correct draw Can I use Left and Right to extract information into separate columns??

Comment: Welcome to SO. A data example with your input and expected output would be helpful indeed.

Comment: try to mix the use of `mid()` & `find()` (find the "-") ..  share us how far u'd get..

Answer (score 0):

*Answer to "Can I use Left and Right to extract information into separate columns?"*

Put the following formulas in two different cells:

`=LEFT([cell_with_score],FIND("-",[cell_with_score])-1)`

and

`=RIGHT([cell_with_score],LEN([cell_with_score])-FIND("-",[cell_with_score]))`

*Note:* [cell_with_score] is a placeholder for a cell in which your score is stored.